# Start With AMPScript => need some help

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I just start with AMSCRIPT, and it's abit difficult to understand for the time being.

If I have a table with two colums :
1) ID of persons (we can have several times the same ID in a column)
2) pets associated (one ID can have for example a cat and later in the table a dog)

What would be the AMSCRIPT to gather all the pets for one person (represented by his ID)

And another question

if I have two tables
table 1 with two colums : ID of persons, pets associated
table 2 with three colums : pets, preffered foods, hobbies

And I want to have an AMSCRIPT which associated ID of persons with prefreed foods & hobbies, how can I do ?

Thank you very much for help, You would save my life :)

Have a good day
Max

Answer (score 2):

### Answer 1

To answer your first question, if you have an additional Data Extension named 'Members Pets' that looks like this:

```
|ID|Pet |
|--|----|
|1 |Dog |
|1 |Cat |
|1 |Fish|
|2 |Dog |
|3 |Cat |
|3 |Fish|
```

Then you need to use the AMPscript functions:

1. `LookupRows()` function to retrieve the rows
2. `rowcount()` to count the rows
3. `row()` to display the rows

Here's an example:

```
%%[
var @id, @pet, @pets, @rowCount, @row
set @id = 3
set @pets = LookupRows('Members Pets','ID',@id)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@pets)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
   set @row = row(@pets,@i) 
   set @pet = field(@row,"Pet")

        if @i == 1 then
          outputline(concat("<ul>"))
        endif
]%%

           <li>%%=v(@pet)=%%</li>

%%[ 
   if @i == @rowcount then
     outputline(concat("</ul>"))
   endif

   next @i 
]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No rows found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

This produces the output given Member ID (in this case 3):

- Cat
- Fish

### Answer 2

To answer your second question, if you have a second data extension named 'Pet Data' that looks like this:

```
|Pet |PrefFood|Hobbies  |
|----|--------|---------|
|Dog |Meat    |walk,play|
|Cat |Fish    |sleep    |
|Fish|Flakes  |swim     |
```

Then expand on your earlier code to include the second Data Extension and use an AMPscript `Lookup()` function to retrieve the respective values:

```
%%[
var @id, @pets, @pet, @rowCount, @rowCountPetData, @row
set @id = 3
set @pets = LookupRows('Members Pets','ID',@id)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@pets)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
   set @row = row(@pets,@i) 
   set @pet = field(@row,'Pet')
   set @prefFood = Lookup('Pet Data','PrefFood','Pet',@pet)
   set @hobbies = Lookup('Pet Data','Hobbies','Pet',@pet)


        if @i == 1 then
          outputline(concat("<table><tr><th>pet</th><th>food</th><th>hobby</th></tr>"))
        endif
]%%

           <tr>
              <td>%%=v(@pet)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@prefFood)=%%</td>
              <td>%%=v(@hobbies)=%%</td>
           </tr>

%%[ 
   if @i == @rowcount then
     outputline(concat("</table>"))
   endif

   next @i 
]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No rows found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

This produces a table containing the pets along with their preferred food and hobbies for the given Member ID:

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

The first question is straight forward, just need to use the LookupRows function, https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/LookupRows.html

This function is a kind of SELECT in SQL (if you know that before), for your case, you may need to write SET @rows = LookupRows('You_DE_Name','ID',@Person_ID)

It returns a rowset object (a collection of rows), then you can use Row function to get one row by giving the row number. https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/Row.html

You may need to use LOOP to get one by one until the end of rowset.

@rows = LookupRows('You_DE_Name','ID',@Person_ID)
FOR @idx = 1 to RowCount(@rows) DO
    row = Row(@rows,@idx)
NEXT @idx

Above code will loop through all rows in @rows, and get each row and you can do whatever you need for that row.

Hope that gives you some light, I am not a experienced amp script programmer, but it is not easy to understand rowset, fields if you never touched programming language.

try to take the example of Excel for understanding,

- rowset is a collection of rows (a table in Excel)
- row is a collection of field (a row in Excel)
- field is a single value (a cell in Excel)